# How to delete all rows of a JTable in Loop?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row

I am trying to delete all rows of my JTable when an action is performed.

I wrote code below:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    int rowCount = model.getRowCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount ; i++){
        model.removeRow(i);
    }
```

But it didn't work as I expected.

Comment: If you want to remove all the rows, why don't you consider to create a new instance of your model and set it as your JTable model? Isn't it faster than removing all the rows one by one?

Comment: @STaefi That might be true, but you'd lose the column and row sorting configuration, in fact, simply using `DefaultTableModel#setRowCount` would be faster, as the table would only need to update it's contents and not it's column model and sorter...

Comment: @MadProgrammer thats right, thank you.

Comment: @Sparrow7000: I think you've checked a wrong condition in your for loop `for (int i = 0; i > rowCount ; i++)` . If you want to remove the rows from first to last order, you should check `i < rowCount` instead. However, it's better to go from last to first.

Comment: @STawfi you are right. But it didn't work properly even after changing the condition.

Answer (score 4):

Each time you remove a row, the row count will change.  Better to continue looping until there are no rows left

```
while (model.getRowCount() > 0) {
    model.removeRow(0);
}
```

Now, if I'm not wrong, you could also just do `model.setRowCount(0)` and it will remove all the rows for you ;)

Comment: Bang on the target http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setRowCount(int)

Answer (score 2):

I searched the net and find out that we should delete the rows of the table from the end of the table instead of the beginning. I wanted to share this information with others.

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    int rowCount = model.getRowCount();
    for (int i = rowCount; i > 0 ; i--){
        model.removeRow(i-1);
    }
```

It worked properly for me. Good Luck.